# Story about lunar settlers who eat soup made of dead people in order to concentrate gold

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the name of a short story: Settlers on the moon(?) make soup out of the body when someone dies. They eat this soup in order to concentrate gold that has accumulated in the body so that after multiple generations they can harvest it for industrial use (to build a spaceship?).

The children are described as "heartbreakingly thin."

I have no idea how old this story might be.

Comment: Honestly this question is why people need to start including memorable phrases. It took me all of five seconds to find this on Google Books; https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22soup%22+%22gold%22+%22moon%22+%22heartbreakingly+thin%22

Comment: Thanks for the Google Books tip! I have used general search engines to no avail. And yes, People Came From Earth is it!

Comment: Like many things in life, it's easy if you know what you're doing and next-to-impossible if you don't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [*People Came from Earth*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91914) (1999) by Stephen Baxter.

There's much talk about 'heartbreakingly thin' children, gold and making a soup, literally, out of the bones of settlers in order to make spaceship components.

> “Ah, but the power of those great thermals, Uncle,” he said, as he accepted the soup. “I can fly miles high without the slightest effort.”
>
> I would have berated him further, which is the prerogative of old age.
> But I didn’t have the heart. He stood before me, eager,
> heartbreakingly thin. Berge always was slender, even compared to the
> rest of us skinny lunar folk; but now he was clearly frail. Even these
> long minutes after landing, he was still panting, and his smooth
> fashionably-shaven scalp (so bare it showed the great bubble profile
> of his lunar-born skull) was dotted with beads of grimy sweat.

and

> I clung to the greater goal: that the atoms of gold and nickel and
> zinc which had coursed in Berge’s blood and bones, killing him like
> the mustard plants of Maginus—killing us all, in fact, at one rate or
> another—would now gather in even greater concentrations in the bodies
> of those who would follow us. Perhaps the pathetic scrap of gold or
> nickel which had cost poor Berge his life would at last, mined, close
> the circuit which would lift the first of our ceramic-hulled ships
> beyond the thick, deadening atmosphere of the Moon.
>
> Perhaps. But it was cold comfort.
>
> We ate the soup, of his dissolved bones and flesh, in solemn silence.
> We took his life’s sole gift, further concentrating the metal traces
> to the far future, short­ening our lives as he had.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the Moon have a thick atmosphere in this story?

Comment: @Eugene - It was terraformed using ice from Jupiter; https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJDif.png